# Android : imgView.getDrawingCache() crops the Bitmap when I save in the storage

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-canvas

I am adding a point on Canvas bitmap. **Scale, Rotate and Move gestures are enabled on the ImageView.** After that, I am saving the image in the external storage through a button click. But the bitmap is getting cropped (the size of bitmap is same as of my custom imageView). I am saving the point on canvas using imgView.getDrawingCache(). **I don't want the saved bitmap to be cropped.**

```
Save Function - 
private void saveFunction() {
    iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = iv.getDrawingCache(true);

  /*  BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
    Bitmap newBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();*/

    String path = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(path + File.separator + "name" + ".png");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.getAbsolutePath(), 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try {
        if (!file.exists())

        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
        ostream.close();
        System.out.println("Rushi : saveFunction : saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My custom ImageView class-
public class

```
DrawImageView extends ImageView {

    private Paint currentPaint;
    public boolean drawRect = false;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public Bitmap newBitmap;
    public Matrix matrix;


    public DrawImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        currentPaint = new Paint();
        currentPaint.setDither(true);
        currentPaint.setColor(0xFF00CC00);
        currentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        currentPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        currentPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        currentPaint.setStrokeWidth(60);
    }

    public void setNewBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        newBitmap = bmp;
    }

    public Bitmap getNewBitmap() {
        return newBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (drawRect) {
            canvas.drawPoint(x, y, currentPaint);
          /*  Matrix matrix = this.getImageMatrix();
            float[] pts = {0, 0};
            matrix.mapPoints(pts);
            System.out.println("Rushi : NewPoint : "+pts[0]+","+pts[1]);*/
           // canvas.drawBitmap(newBitmap, getImageMatrix(), null);
        }
    }

}
```

So basically, on clicking a button I am drawing a point, and then saving the image.

[image: This is right after I clicked 'Add checkpoint'. The green point appears.]

[image: But when I opened my storage. The image is cropped]

Comment: so why, why dont you use `Matrix#mapPoints`? can you tell me ? what does `System.out.println("Rushi : NewPoint : "+pts[0]+","+pts[1]);` show?

Comment: I did a bit of study. Turns out that, when your perform matrix.postScale() or matrix.postRotate(), the actual points are changed. The mapPoints() will update the original point array. I think mapPoints() won't help me attaching the point on my canvas. Not sure. I would still appreciate if you solve my previous question. My job depends on that. Kindly help.

Comment: so what are the values of `pts[0]` and `pts[1]`? did you check the logcat window?

Comment: Just checked it. pts[0] and pts[1] is the top-left corner point of the bitmap. It changes every time I move or scale the image. So what to do next? The drawn point is still at the same place.

Comment: `"The drawn point is still at the same place. "` this is because you draw it by calling: `canvas.drawPoint(x, y, ...)` - does `x` and `y` change? if not, so how do you want your point to be at different place?

Comment: Brilliant. This is almost done. When i pass pts[0] and pts[1] the point actually moves with the image. **It is sticking**. But this is what I want. Please read carefully. When I press the 'Add checkpoint' button, **(please look at screenshots from previous question)**, the point should stick at location of red circle like image, and so on. What to do?

Comment: so change {0, 0} with different values

Comment: I will try that now. Thanks for the help. You have been a great help. God bless you!

Comment: use [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/PpuvARaB) and replace `float[] pts = {0, 0};` with, for example `float[] pts = {200, 400};`

Comment: I replace my custom ImagView class with this. Right?

Comment: just call `setContentView(new IV(this));` inside your `Activity#onCreate` method

Comment: I will let you know soon. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: I just replaced my custom image view. I passed the red circle coordinates to float[] pts, but the added point is not moving at all. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: did you run my code? and the red circle does not move when you scroll/scale/rotate the image? how come?

Comment: Yes, I ran your code. Red circle appeared but does not move when i scale or move. Should i send you my code via Google Drive link?

Comment: did yoiu run my code without **ANY** changes? just copy/paste? https://pastebin.com/raw/PpuvARaB - all you can change is `R.drawable.chrome` to some other image you have

Comment: My setContentView() is setContentView(R.layout.activity_main). Inside my XML file, I added your custom image view. That's the only change I did. Because I need to load image from gallery to this custom image view. What should I do?

Comment: what i said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067238/android-imgview-getdrawingcache-crops-the-bitmap-when-i-save-in-the-storage#comment93054462_53067238) - just run it and check how it works - later on you can change anything you like

Comment: Please check my new question. It is related to this.